# haskell length runtime O(1) or O(n)

Tags: haskell

I was working on a Haskell assignment and I was trying think of ways to make my code faster.
For example, my factors function below finds the number of divisors of some integer.

```
factors :: Int -> Int
factors x = length [n | n <- [1..x], mod x n == 0]
```

However, it occurred to me that I could make my code faster by avoiding usage of "length".

```
factors :: Int -> Int
factors x = go 1
  where
    go :: Int -> Int
    go i
      | i == x        = 1
      | mod x i == 0  = 1 + go (i + 1)
      | otherwise     = go (i + 1)
```

I was wondering if Haskell's length function is O(n) like strlen() in C or O(1) like String.length() in Java.

Also, is there a better or more efficient of writing my code?

Comment: But this is not a string.

Comment: How about ArrayList.size(), then? The point is the complexity, not the specific type.

Comment: It seems likely that after the compiler optimizes this code, the evaluation of the first `factors` expression won't even involve constructing a list at all. Keep in mind how lazy evaluation works - you're not "constructing a list, then counting its size" - you're counting the list elements *as they're being generated*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a theoretical perspective, we can not know whether *`length` is θ(n)*, we know that it is *O(n)*, but it is technically possible that Haskell implements it faster for known lists.

Since a Haskell compiler could be free to implement a list whatever way they want to. But nevertheless **it does not matter**, since in that case *generating* the list in the first place will take *θ(n)*.

Note that even if the compiler uses a more dedicated datastructure, Haskell is lazy, so your *list comprehension* does not result in a complete list, but more in a function that *can* generate a list lazily.

Finally if we would evaluate the list comprehension eagerly, then it would again require *O(n)* to first generate the list in the first place. So even if obtaining the length was very fast, then generating the list would require *O(n)* as a lower bound. So regardless what the efficiency of `length` is, the algorithm will still scale linearly with the input.

Your own implementation again uses *O(n)* (and is not very safe to be honest). Nevertheless, you can easily speedup the factorization of a number to *O(sqrt n)*:

```
factors :: Int -> Int
factors x = go 1
  where
    go :: Int -> Int
    go i | i2 > x = 0
         | i2 == x = 1
         | mod x i == 0 = 2 + go (i+1)
         | otherwise = go (i + 1)
        where i2 = i*i
```

Here we enumerate from 1 to sqrt(n). Each time we find a factor `a`, we know that there is a *co*-factor `b = x/a`. As long as `a` is not equal to sqrt(x), we know that those are different. In case `a` is equal to sqrt(x), we know that `a` is equal to `b` and thus we count this as one.

That being said, there are definitely faster ways to do it. It is a topic with a lot of research that has yielded more efficient algorithms. I'm not suggesting that the above is the fastest, but it is definitely a huge improvement in terms of time complexity.

Comment: "From a theoretical perspective, we can not know whether length is O(n). Since a Haskell compiler could be free to implement a list whatever way they want to."

I don't think it's up to the compiler. [`length` in base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#length) is O(n). It's hard to imagine a compiler that could optimize that to constant time.

Comment: @JeffBurka: I agree that it is very unlikely, but mind that (a) `base` is an implementation of `length`; and (b) afaik the Haskell report does not talk about how to implement certain datastructures and/or optimize them. I definitely agree that the odds are not very likely. Nevertheless it does not really matter, since constructing the list already has *O(n)* time complexity.

Comment: @Greg: that is not true. `x/2` is for instance usually greater. The point is that if we see that `2` is a factor, we can count both `2` and `x/2` at the same time. We do not need to investigate possible factors greater than `sqrt(x)`, since once we reach `sqrt(x)`, we know what these are.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, the Report specifies lists explicitly as `data [a] = [] | a : [a]` in [§6.1.3](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1200006.1.3), and specifies that `length` is O(n) in [§20](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch20.html#TBL-257).  (Indeed, for this type, it's impossible to implement `length` in less than Θ(n) time.)  You are correct that you can't rule out a caching or memoization based evaluation strategy – but this wouldn't affect the first call to `length xs`, only subsequent ones.  (And yes, technically O(1) ∊ O(n).)

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky: I know that the report says `data [a] = [] | a : [a]`. The point is that this is on *specification* level. How it works behind the curtains is a matter of implementation as far as I know. For instance one can not say that tail will work in *O(1)*, since a compiler could decide to implement it another way. I'm not saying there is much *animo* to do it another way, but one must be careful making claims about the internal workings of functions.

Comment: The nonstrict semantics of the Report leave very little room for cleverness in list implementation. Could a compiler try to infer that a list is finite and fully defined and do something special? I suppose so, but that sounds hard and brittle.

Answer (score 4):

In my estimation, contrary to the accepted answer, you *can* in fact infer the complexity of `length` (and many other functions) just by looking at the definition of `[a]`:

```
Prelude> :info []
data [] a = [] | a : [a]    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
```

Lists are inductively-defined; you can see from that definition (which is *almost* just regular haskell) that at the top level a list is either the constructor `[]` or `:`. Clearly `length` must recurse `n` times on this structure and so would have to be O(n).

It's very important to be able to reason at least intuitively in this way, in particular about lists which are ubiquitous. e.g. quick what's the complexity of `(!!)`?

If you want to do a deep dive into formally reasoning about time complexity in the presence of laziness then you'll need to pick up "Purely Functional Data Structures" by Okasaki.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, is there a better or more efficient of writing my code?

Integer factorization is one of the most famous problems. There surely have been proposed a lot of algorithms for that, even if I am not expert enough to make a recommendation (CS.SE is around the corner, and can help on that, if needed). None of such proposals is polynomial time, but this doesn't stop them to be faster than the trivial approach.

Even without looking at the literature, a few simple optimizations can be found.

- The original code scans the whole list `[1..x]`, but this is not needed. We could stop at `sqrt x`, since after that there are no longer divisors.
- Even more: after we find a divisor `m`, we could divide `x` by `m` (as many times as possible), and recurse with this new number. E.g. if `x = 1000` after we try `m=2`, we compute `1000 -> 500 -> 250 -> 125`, and then find the new divisors (larger than `2`) in `125`. Note how this made the number much smaller.

I will leave implementing this strategies in Haskell as an exercise :-P

Answer (score 1):

Building the list with the list comprehension already takes `O(n)`. Therefore there is not much overhead when using a length function which should have complexity `O(n)` in the worst case.